# Ajax request is sent but can't be accessed with $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Ok so this is my first question on stack overflow so sorry for my mistakes and also I'm sorry if I have grammatical problems I'm not a English/US native.
This is my code:

```
var test = "randomtext";
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'likes.php',
   data: {test:test},
   success: function(msg){ 
        alert('Success!');
   }
});
```

It alerts 'Succes' but when I access it on the likes.php it shows this error:

Notice: Undefined index: test in D:\xampp\htdocs\Project\likes.php on line 7

Also my likes.php looks like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");

session_start();

$name = $_POST["test"]; 

echo $name;
```

I tried all the possibilities nothing worked. Thanks for help!

Comment: have you tried printing the `$_POST` content, using `print_r` or `var_dump` ?

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump`?

Comment: also, in your ajax request, you use "test" as a key, and as a variable... so JS my misunderstand it... maybe your key is "randomtext" (content of `test` var)

Comment: change `data: {test:test}` to `data: {"test":test}`

Comment: I had the same issue when using a local server like Wamp and Xamp. maybe the problem is with server configuration.

Comment: Same result... I tried this before asking the question...

Comment: Yes I thought about that but I saw other guys who were using xampp and this worked for them..

Comment: `dataType  : 'json'` ?

Comment: Already tried it nothing happens....

Comment: On likes.php try use `echo json_encode($_POST);` and check with browser console returned value .

Comment: I figured it out, actually it does what I want with that errors so it is strange but it works thanks for your interest!

Comment: You should post your solution as your own answer and accept it for future readers (or future self)

Comment: I tried but it says that I can just in 2 days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what you have to do is actually do a `mysqli_query` or whatever you need your ajax to execute and it will work even if you get errors which is very strange but it works. And I noticed that the *errors* are not errors are *notices*. But thanks everybody for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

Use `dataType:"json",` as you are using json

```
 var test = "randomtext";
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'likes.php',
   dataType:"json",
   data: {test:test},
   success: function(msg){ 
    alert('Success!');
   }
 });
```

Comment: Comment all code in php and try only this `echo  $name = $_POST["test"]; ` anf check again?

Comment: I tried var_dump and it returns NULL I think is because of I run it on a local server....

Comment: I don't get any error when I send it but on the likes.php it's saying that index doesn't exists..